# ComboBox and ComboBoxItem names are null

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have a list of messages that is sorted by the selected option (time, name or group ID) from a ComboBox.
I added a ComboBox with Items to my xaml:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="sort_dropdown" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="828,219,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" SelectedIndex="0">
        <ComboBoxItem x:Name="time_sort" Content="Time" Selected="time_sort_Selected"/>
        <ComboBoxItem x:Name="nickname_sort" Content="Nickname" Selected="nickname_sort_Selected"/>
        <ComboBoxItem x:Name="groupId_sort" Content="Group ID" Selected="groupId_sort_Selected"/>
    </ComboBox>
```

to have the list reordered, I wrote a function in the cs file:

```
private void reorder()
    {
        if (time_sort.IsSelected)
            fill_chat(MessageSorting.DateSort(Globals.MSG_LOCAL_LIST, ascendingOrder));
        else if (nickname_sort.IsSelected)
            fill_chat(MessageSorting.UserNameSort(Globals.MSG_LOCAL_LIST, ascendingOrder));
        else fill_chat(MessageSorting.GroupIdSort(Globals.MSG_LOCAL_LIST, ascendingOrder));
    }
```

When Run, I get a NullReferenceException. And upon debugging I found that the objects name reference to null.

Examples: time_sort = null. sort_dropdown = null. and etc.

Changing attributes on the xaml doesn't help because there's no reference to read those attributes.
Thanks.

Update: This isn't the main window, and I noticed when I run the code that this window class runs before I call the .show function on it. For some reason the code in it is executed without being called.

Update 2: I have the following code:

```
public MainLoggedWindow()
    {

        MessageBox.Show("Before initialization");
        InitializeComponent();
        MessageBox.Show("after initialization");
    }
```

when running, the first MessageBox shows up but the second doesn't.
the reorder() function is called from the following function:

```
        private void order_dropdown_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ascendingOrder = !ascendingOrder;
        reorder();
    }
```

ascendingOrder is a bool that saves the current sorting order. There's another comboBox with 2 items (Ascending or Descending), Every time the user changes it's choice this function runs.

Update 3: Following the Call Stack while debugging shows that `initializeComponent();` calls `order_dropdown_SelectionChanged(...)` which calls `reorder()`.

Solved.

Narrowing down the problem: `initializeComponent();` Caused `order_dropdown_SelectionChanged(...)` to run.

Explanation: On the ComboBox declaration in the xaml, `selectedIndex` attribute is defined like this: `SelectedIndex="0"`. So part of the initialization is creating the ComboBox and setting `selectedindex=0` which instantly triggers the `order_dropdown_SelectionChanged(...)` function. Now since the ComboBox items weren't created yet the name reference was null and the program crashed.

Solution: Don't define both `selectedIndex` attribute and `_SelectionChanged(...)` in the xaml. Personally I removed the `selectedIndex` attribute and defined it programmatically after `initializeComponent();` is called.

Comment: When is this reorder function being called? Is it before the `InitializeComponent()` call in the form's constructor?

Comment: I cannot reproduce, `x:Name` works for me as long as it is called after `InitializeComponent`.

Comment: reorder is called only when a different sorting option is selected. It is never called before `InitializeComponent()`

Comment: Are you sure it is not being called when the class is created/initialized?

Comment: Yes it is supposed to be called only as a response to a selection.
I updated the question as I found something while debugging.
It is definitely an initialization related problem.

Comment: It would probably help if you shared the code where you are calling the function. As people have said, it seems to be getting called too soon during the setup of the window. If you set a breakpoint in this function and two more in the constructor where InitializeComponent is called (one before and one after), you should see it return from InitializeComponent before your method is called. If your method is called before then, it is probably being called too early.

Comment: Updated again with related code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As part of the `InitializeComponent` it is setting the selection of your `order_dropdown`; but this is occurring before the named controls have been set up. So your `reorder` method needs to defend against that by wrapping its current contents within a test for `if(time_sort!=null)` as a way of determining whether the initialize has completed.

Comment: thanks! just managed to figure it out myself around the same time you posted this :)